# Selenium not finding elements on specific website

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium on https://www.ticketswap.be/ with the following code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.ticketswap.be/')
login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/button')
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-3a159bb5ece9> in <module>()
      1 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
      2 driver.get('https://www.ticketswap.be/')
----> 3 login_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/button')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    245                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    246             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 247         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    248 
    249     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="__next"]/div[5]/div/nav/ul/li[4]/button"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=100.0.4896.127)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x562ead5a71b3 <unknown>
#1 0x562ead2962c3 <unknown>
#2 0x562ead2cc7a0 <unknown>
#3 0x562ead2cc9c1 <unknown>
#4 0x562ead301127 <unknown>
#5 0x562ead2ea11d <unknown>
#6 0x562ead2fee6c <unknown>
#7 0x562ead2ea463 <unknown>
#8 0x562ead2c063c <unknown>
#9 0x562ead2c1b05 <unknown>
#10 0x562ead5cba90 <unknown>
#11 0x562ead5dd378 <unknown>
#12 0x562ead5dd09c <unknown>
#13 0x562ead5dd902 <unknown>
#14 0x562ead615f0b <unknown>
#15 0x562ead5ddb61 <unknown>
#16 0x562ead5bffd3 <unknown>
#17 0x562ead5e72b8 <unknown>
#18 0x562ead5e744a <unknown>
#19 0x562ead600291 <unknown>
```

I have tried to use other elements to find the login button but none work on this specific website. I also used the same code on other website to locate elements there and it worked. Can anyone help me out to make this work?

**Edit:** I am implementing the proposed solution of @cruisepandey in Google Colab with the following code:

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.ticketswap.be/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accepteer']"))).click()
```

But I am still getting some the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-f6d2b0806de3> in <module>()
      6 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
      7 
----> 8 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accepteer']"))).click()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     87             if time.time() > end_time:
     88                 break
---> 89         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     90 
     91     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55a6dc2a91b3 <unknown>
#1 0x55a6dbf982c3 <unknown>
#2 0x55a6dbfce7a0 <unknown>
#3 0x55a6dbfce9c1 <unknown>
#4 0x55a6dc003127 <unknown>
#5 0x55a6dbfec11d <unknown>
#6 0x55a6dc000e6c <unknown>
#7 0x55a6dbfec463 <unknown>
#8 0x55a6dbfc263c <unknown>
#9 0x55a6dbfc3b05 <unknown>
#10 0x55a6dc2cda90 <unknown>
#11 0x55a6dc2df378 <unknown>
#12 0x55a6dc2df09c <unknown>
#13 0x55a6dc2df902 <unknown>
#14 0x55a6dc317f0b <unknown>
#15 0x55a6dc2dfb61 <unknown>
#16 0x55a6dc2c1fd3 <unknown>
#17 0x55a6dc2e92b8 <unknown>
#18 0x55a6dc2e944a <unknown>
#19 0x55a6dc302291 <unknown>
#20 0x7f9561dc26db <unknown>
```

Comment: What are you trying to scrape? Sure it's not behind a login?

Comment: Where is this button on this page https://www.ticketswap.be/

Comment: @0stone0 , it is behind a login. I am trying to locate the login button on the homepage which is called 'Inloggen'

Comment: @cruisepandey , it's the button called 'Inloggen'

Comment: @SDR3078: See my response below

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

1. Click on accept button.
2. Click on close language button.

Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://www.ticketswap.be/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Accepteer']"))).click()
    print("Clicked on accept cookies button successfully")
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='CloseRounded']"))).click()
        print("clicked on close language button")
    except:
        print("Could not click on close language button")
        pass
except:
    print("Could not click accept cookies button successfully")
    pass

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Inloggen']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Output:**

```
Clicked on accept cookies button successfully
clicked on close language button
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to implement in Google Colab, but unfortunately I still get an error

Comment: I edited my post to include the error

Comment: No, you should use try and except suggest by me, cause sometime that accept button is popping up sometime it does not.

Comment: Also, the relevant code is this `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Inloggen']"))).click()` in order to make this work you need to have `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='CloseRounded']"))).click()` line prior to it, so that close action could be performed.

Comment: Still getting an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f0e6f5bcdd7c> in <module>()
     19     pass
     20 
---> 21 wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Inloggen']"))).click()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     87             if time.time() > end_time:
     88                 break
---> 89         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stac

Comment: Update the question with the exact code that you've been trying.

Comment: It's kind of weird that this code works fine in local and does not really work in google colab, I tried by myself and could not really make it to run on Google colab. However, I did see that even the first click itself not working, may be we are missing a configuration. This is strange !